# How can I save an Object like an Image Classifier prepared using Keras to my any file using Python?

Tags: python, pickle

I have an object created using keras. I want to save it to a file(serialize) it, so that I can re-use it later for prediction.
The following is my object:
classifier

I am trying to use pickle, but it is giving me following error

```
import pickle

file_pi = open('Dog_Cat_Identifier.obj', 'w')

pickle.dump(classifier, file_pi)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>      pickle.dump(classifier, file_pi)
>
> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Can I know, what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can save keras model using the `save` method provided by the package

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5') 

model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

You can load back your classifier using the `load_model()` function which is in `keras.models`